# Import troubles

Tags: python, import, importerror

Here is part of my module:  gm.py

```
def avg_list(list): 
    sum = 0
    for num in list:
        sum += num

    avg = float(sum)/len(list)
    print avg



def median(list):
    i = len(list)
    if not i%2: # if i divided my 2 has no remainder

        return (list[(i/2)-1]+list[i/2])/2.0 # return the value of this block


    else:
        median = sorted(list)[len(list)/2] # otherwise, when the list is sorted, the index of len(s) / 2 is the middle number.
        return median
```

When I save this as 'gm.py' and open a new script page to input the following function:

```
import gm
def stats(list):

    stats = {}  # empty dict named stats
    stats['average'] = avg_list(list) # Stats(key)[average] = mean of the list of numbers [values]
    stats['median'] = median(list) # same for median
    return stats
```

When I run this program and type stats([2,3,4,5,6])... I get an error saying global variable avg_list not defined. I'm not sure if I'm doing the import correctly?
Do I need to do something like... from gm import avg_list() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either reference the functions on the module object:

```
import gm
def stats(list):

    stats = {}  # empty dict named stats
    stats['average'] = gm.avg_list(list) # Stats(key)[average] = mean of the list of numbers [values]
    stats['median'] = gm.median(list) # same for median
    return stats
```

or import the functions directly into the global namespace:

```
from gm import avg_list, median
def stats(list):

    stats = {}  # empty dict named stats
    stats['average'] = avg_list(list) # Stats(key)[average] = mean of the list of numbers [values]
    stats['median'] = median(list) # same for median
    return stats
```

Note that **you should not name a variable `list`**. This masks the built-in `list()` function / type and can cause confusing errors later if you need to use it.

You can write

```
stats = {}  # empty dict named stats
stats['average'] = avg_list(list) # Stats(key)[average] = mean of the list of numbers [values]
stats['median'] = median(list) # same for median
return stats
```

as

```
stats = {'average': avg_list(list), 'median': median(list)}
return stats # or just return the dict literal, no real need to give it a name.
```

I think you should look at the first branch of your `median` function. Does the list need to be sorted there too, like in the second branch?

Your `avg_list` function is also masking a built-in function, `sum()`, which you could use here instead of manually adding:

```
def avg_list(list): 
    avg = float(sum(list))/len(list)
    print avg
```

Finally, look at the last line of that function -- it's `print`ing the `avg`, but `stats` is expecting it to `return` the `avg`. The two aren't the same.

Comment: If I add sorted to the first branch, I receive a TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

Comment: @G.G You can't just wrap the whole thing in `sorted`, I mean you need to sort the list _before_ looking up the median, whether the list has an odd or even number of entries. Try just adding `list = sorted(list)` or `list.sort()` to the top of the function and get rid of the other calls to `sorted`.

Comment: @afg ah, my mistake... I can do that. I ran the program again with the proper imports and came back with a:

>>> stats([2,5,6,7,8])
5.6
{'average': None, 'median': 6}

Comment: I fixed it so instead of print the avg, it's returning it. Sorry for the noob question... how do you shade certain parts of your sentence to specify as code?

Comment: Use backticks / backquotes / reverse quotes -- `\`` -- next to the `1` on the key with the `~` on my keyboard. See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3878/discussion-between-g-g-and-agf)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the module name first (`gm.avg_list()` and `gm.median()`) like so:

```
import gm
def stats(list):

    stats = {}  # empty dict named stats
    stats['average'] = gm.avg_list(list) # Stats(key)[average] = mean of the list of numbers [values]
    stats['median'] = gm.median(list) # same for median
    return stats
```

---

Some Reference links and more info:

[PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

[A guide to Python Namespaces](http://bytebaker.com/2008/07/30/python-namespaces/) on the differences between `from blah import foo` and `import blah`

> - import SomeModule
>
> This is the simplest way to do imports and generally recommended. You
>   get access to the module’s namespace provided you use the module’s
>   name as a prefix. This means that you can have names in your program
>   which are the same as those in the module, but you’ll be able to use
>   both of them. It’s also helpful when you’re importing a large number
>   of modules as you see which module a particular name belongs to.
>
> - from SomeModule import SomeName
>
> This imports a name (or a few, separated by commas) from a module’s
>   namespace directly into the program’s. To use the name you imported,
>   you no longer have to use a prefix, just the name directly. This can
>   be useful if you know for certain you’ll only need to use a few names.
>   The downside is that you can’t use the name you imported for something
>   else in your own program. For example, you could use add() instead of
>   Integer.add(), but if your program has an add() function, you’ll lose
>   access to the Integer’s add() function.